# Gantt Chart Scale - Zoom out to Quarter

Tags: gantt-view

Is there a way I can make the Gantt chart scale to display in monthly/quarterly by zooming out default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="URL for jquery-min.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
    $("th[title='Title']").css({"width":"400px"})
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) WebPartWPQ2_JSGridController.ZoomOutGantt()
      }, 2000)
    });
    </script>
```

This script helped me to scale and display the gantt chart in quarter.

Comment: is it possible to make the Gantt Chart show only current week data ?! and also have a search option to look for previous weeks etc?

Answer (score 1):

The complete function below works well (if you have a single gantt on your page). I found that I sometimes got race conditions where the gantt wasn't rendered before I messed with it so this is avoided by doing it in a timeout to allow time for it to render.

```
$(function(){
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ScrollGanttToToday,'jsgrid.js');
    function ScrollGanttToToday(){

        setTimeout(function(){                      
            var theGanttGridObject = $("div [id$='_ListViewWebPartJSGrid']")[0].jsgrid;

            theGanttGridObject.SetGanttZoomLevel(theGanttGridObject.GetGanttZoomLevel()+3);
            theGanttGridObject.SetSplitterPosition(600);
            theGanttGridObject.ScrollGanttToDate(new Date());
            theGanttGridObject.DisableEditing();
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked for me when added to a Script Editor WP on a Site Page with a Task List Gantt View added